# Can PartCover work with WCF (remotely running)?

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, partcover

Can PartCover coverage for remotely running binaries ?

Answer (score 0):

Profilers like partcover need to be running on the same machine as the assemblies being covered (well the COM object that does the instrumenting bit) - this is because they need to hook into the CLR runtime and intercept calls that allow them to instrument the build that then gather coverage. The COM object that partcover uses currently needs to be local to the process it sends it details to process and store the results.